# How to subscribe facebook pages to my facebook app using Graph API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-messenger-bot

Currently, I am developing a messenger bot. For this purpose, I created a facebook app from facebook developer platform.

Now I need to subscribe facebook pages to my app using graph API, so for any message from the page, I can respond from my server.

I find one in Graph API [Doc](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/subscribed_apps/).

When I try it in the [graph API explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/subscribed_apps/), I am encountering an error.

I followed the following steps:

```
1. Create a new app and page.
2. Get the page access token from my app.
3. In graph api explorer, Select my desired facebook app(newly created) from the drop-down menu.
5. When I was getting the user access token, made sure, I took permission for both 'publish_pages' and 'manage_pages'
6. Replaced the {page-id} with 'page access token'
```

I am getting this error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#803) Some of the aliases you requested do not exist: EAAfIhxeHRsYBAD3VNK3BzOqkyhxOL8aZBPnUVZA94olvxYrZA93rNGKwUIJFFhS91ogEbBBlGQJxYGSyJe5I1dNntxsPnqNYFkoI1NcEroa4TunvZCWZAZA06U0UcpvUu5HgBIifGqZCWTDcUH6sCe7BCWdljg5LU7OjwbRgyLe2nCILijnuGqH",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 803,
    "fbtrace_id": "BUv80nDC3jo"
  }
}
```

I sent this code from graph API Explorer:

```
curl -i -X GET \
 "https://graph.facebook.com/v3.1/EAAfIhxeHRsYBAD3VNK3BzOqkyhxOL8aZBPnUVZA94olvxYrZA93rNGKwUIJFFhS91ogEbBBlGQJxYGSyJe5I1dNntxsPnqNYFkoI1NcEroa4TunvZCWZAZA06U0UcpvUu5HgBIifGqZCWTDcUH6sCe7BCWdljg5LU7OjwbRgyLe2nCILijnuGqH/subscribed_apps?access_token=EAAfIhxeHRsYBAD8dPXQ6jR06FPFhsECXlALtumbecpEV1iZAk1BRFd580J3NEZBrH8mmn7DWZA9NqlefpskmpMjbZA7HrmdmLVhWmOsHOHzVS1nHLNizqX8ODAItZARTiIig34NZCbXnfwOyRqewiKvnh6fMIwEA4sVICGtFTEJXdsVUiTkZAkDrAI9pbZAAu5KQW5f6ZAktXvQZDZD"
```

FULL DEBUG INFORMATION:

````
==== Query
  curl -i -X GET \
   "https://graph.facebook.com/v3.1/EAAfIhxeHRsYBAD3VNK3BzOqkyhxOL8aZBPnUVZA94olvxYrZA93rNGKwUIJFFhS91ogEbBBlGQJxYGSyJe5I1dNntxsPnqNYFkoI1NcEroa4TunvZCWZAZA06U0UcpvUu5HgBIifGqZCWTDcUH6sCe7BCWdljg5LU7OjwbRgyLe2nCILijnuGqH/subscribed_apps?access_token=<access token sanitized>"
==== Access Token Info
  {
    "perms": [
      "manage_pages",
      "pages_manage_instant_articles",
      "pages_show_list",
      "publish_pages",
      "read_page_mailboxes",
      "pages_messaging",
      "pages_messaging_phone_number",
      "pages_messaging_subscriptions",
      "public_profile"
    ],
    "user_id": 1077587462403179,
    "app_id": 2190807377856198
  }
==== Parameters
- Query Parameters


  {}
- POST Parameters


  {}
==== Response
  {
    "error": {
      "message": "(#803) Some of the aliases you requested do not exist: EAAfIhxeHRsYBAD3VNK3BzOqkyhxOL8aZBPnUVZA94olvxYrZA93rNGKwUIJFFhS91ogEbBBlGQJxYGSyJe5I1dNntxsPnqNYFkoI1NcEroa4TunvZCWZAZA06U0UcpvUu5HgBIifGqZCWTDcUH6sCe7BCWdljg5LU7OjwbRgyLe2nCILijnuGqH",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 803,
      "fbtrace_id": "BUv80nDC3jo"
    }
  }
==== Debug Information from Graph API Explorer
- https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/2190807377856198?method=GET&path=EAAfIhxeHRsYBAD3VNK3BzOqkyhxOL8aZBPnUVZA94olvxYrZA93rNGKwUIJFFhS91ogEbBBlGQJxYGSyJe5I1dNntxsPnqNYFkoI1NcEroa4TunvZCWZAZA06U0UcpvUu5HgBIifGqZCWTDcUH6sCe7BCWdljg5LU7OjwbRgyLe2nCILijnuGqH%2Fsubscribed_apps&version=v3.1```


  [1]: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=%7Bpage-id%7D%2Fsubscribed_apps&version=v3.1
````

Comment: Your step 6 is wrong, why would you replace the page _id_ with a _token_?

Comment: I tried replacing it using the facebook page id, but the error message says, "(#210) A page access token is required to request this resource."

Comment: Well you need to supply _both_ … The page id as part of the path, and the token as a parameter.

Comment: Where should I place the 'page-access-token'? Can you give me a sample structure of the request?

Comment: Start with the chapter on how Graph API works maybe? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/overview/

Comment: Thank you very much, as you said, I had to send both, page access token and page Id. Now I can subscribe to the page. All I have to do is, put the page_access_token to [Access Token] section. Thank you very much.